What does "Single-Ended Primary Inductor" mean?
SEPIC stands for Single-Ended Primary Inductor Converter. Could anyone explain what "Single-Ended Primary Inductor" means in this context?

(Image from schematic of SEPIC in wikipedia here)

Let's start with the term single-ended and I quote from Topology Key to Power Density in Isolated DC-DC Converters: -

Isolated power converter topologies can be classified as either
single-ended or double-ended depending on the usage of the B-H curve.
During the operation, if the flux swings in only one quadrant of the
B-H curve, then the topology is classified as single-ended. If the
flux swings in two quadrants of the B-H curve, then the topology is
classified as double-ended. For a given set of requirements, a
double-ended topology requires a smaller core than a single-ended
topology and does not need an additional reset winding. Table 1 lists
several of the most popular isolated topologies and the power range
these topologies had been historically employed.

The SEPIC uses a primary inductor that is single ended in that current always flows into it from the input supply on the left (as shown in the OP's image).
Why is this inductor termed primary? It's termed primary because the SEPIC uses two inductors. The other inductor is called the secondary inductor and, note that they can be magnetically coupled under certain circumstances thus making them into a transformer. Primary and secondary are transformer terms also.

Thanks! To make sure, is it called 'primary inductor' just because there is a primary inductor in the topology?

To distinguish it from the other inductor @hana

@Andy: Isn't the secondary inductor also single-ended as the current flows in only one direction? Which would would have been more appropriate- Single ended dual inductor converter Vs Single ended primary inductor converter?
